# JS input sum output as currency format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, format

I use the following code to add 2 values of an input and then I display it as the result.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var val1 = +$(".value1").val();
    var val2 = +$(".value2").val();
    $("#result").val(val1*val2);
});
$('.input').blur(function(){
    var val1 = +$(".value1").val();
    var val2 = +$(".value2").val();
    $("#result").val(val1*val2);
});
```

This works fine, but just outputs a standard number format i.e 9000 I want to make it display $9,000 or just 9,000.

I am using the below code which allows me to have an input box with `data-type="currency"` and that displays fine i.e. $9,000.

But when I try to add it to my "result" input box it is just displaying as standard numbers is there anyway of merging my `val1*val2` function with the input output?

```
$("input[data-type='currency']").on({
    keyup: function() {
      formatCurrency($(this));
    },
    blur: function() { 
      formatCurrency($(this), "blur");
    }
});


function formatNumber(n) {
  // format number 1000000 to 1,234,567
  return n.replace(/\D/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
}


function formatCurrency(input, blur) {
  // appends $ to value, validates decimal side
  // and puts cursor back in right position.
  
  // get input value
  var input_val = input.val();
  
  // don't validate empty input
  if (input_val === "") { return; }
  
  // original length
  var original_len = input_val.length;

  // initial caret position 
  var caret_pos = input.prop("selectionStart");
    
  // check for decimal
  if (input_val.indexOf(".") >= 0) {

    // get position of first decimal
    // this prevents multiple decimals from
    // being entered
    var decimal_pos = input_val.indexOf(".");

    // split number by decimal point
    var left_side = input_val.substring(0, decimal_pos);
    var right_side = input_val.substring(decimal_pos);

    // add commas to left side of number
    left_side = formatNumber(left_side);

    // validate right side
    right_side = formatNumber(right_side);
    
    // On blur make sure 2 numbers after decimal
    if (blur === "blur") {
      right_side += "00";
    }
    
    // Limit decimal to only 2 digits
    right_side = right_side.substring(0, 2);

    // join number by .
    input_val = "$" + left_side + "." + right_side;

  } else {
    // no decimal entered
    // add commas to number
    // remove all non-digits
    input_val = formatNumber(input_val);
    input_val = "$" + input_val;
    
    // final formatting
    if (blur === "blur") {
      input_val += ".00";
    }
  }
  
  // send updated string to input
  input.val(input_val);

  // put caret back in the right position
  var updated_len = input_val.length;
  caret_pos = updated_len - original_len + caret_pos;
  input[0].setSelectionRange(caret_pos, caret_pos);
}
```

Comment: Please provide sample HTML in a demo snippet using the editor so we can see all aspects of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `toLocaleString` with  `style: "currency"` and other option's.

Example:

```js
//Get your value, I hard coded it for example
var val1 = "300"; //+$(".value1").val();
var val2 = "30"; //+$(".value2").val();
var result = val1 * val2;

var myFormat = {
  style: "currency",
  currency: "USD",
  currencyDisplay: "symbol",
  minimumFractionDigits: 0
}

$("#result").val(result.toLocaleString("en-US", myFormat));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='result' />
```